# Am I using multiple scala versions?

Tags: scala, maven

I am new to Scala and Spark. I made the simple code and it successfully ran on my local machine. So, I made the `.jar` files using maven and copied them into my clusters machine to test it on the distributed system. However, I started my command, the console throws the error as below.

```
*******CLASSPATH =  ********
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I already googled it and found that the class name should be `package name + class name`. But it didn't worked for my case. And I found another cause that I might be using multiple scala versions. So I checked my `pom.xml` to ensure my scala and spark versions. I changed the version name according to the versions cluster use, but also the result was same.

Below is my pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sclee.scala0</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala_tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.10</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>


  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>scala-tools.org</id>
      <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>

          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

And when I tried to clean, compile and package using maven package, there are some warnings found. (I am not sure that this warnings might be relevant to my result.But to resolve this issue, I attached the log message as below).

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7536 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/usr/local/intellij/idea-IC-163.10154.41/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/usr/local/intellij/idea-IC-163.10154.41/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.3.2 clean compile package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.sclee.scala0:scala_tutorial:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 92, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin is missing. @ line 65, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building scala_tutorial 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/org/scala-tools/maven-scala-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to scala-tools.org (http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases): peer not authenticated
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/target/classes at 1486089232696
[WARNING] warning: there were 2 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[WARNING] one warning found
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 6 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (compile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (compile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:testCompile (test-compile) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.10.4
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.10:0.8.0 requires scala version: 2.10.5
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.scala,**/*.java,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[WARNING] No source files found.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ scala_tutorial ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/dst/Documents/01_Intellij_workspace/scala_tutorial/target/scala_tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.990s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 02 21:34:00 EST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/291M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The Scala version cluster uses is `2.10.4`. So I tried to change all the versions in the pom.xml. And the my scala code is as below. It is simple tasks to transform my data using DataFrame.

What I want to use my jar files written by scala and test it on the cluster mode. And my questions is there are any wrong process (version issue or anything) that you looked strange? Any help will be appreciated.

```
package com.sclee.scala0
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount").setMaster("local[*]")
    // Create a Scala Spark Context.
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._


    val df  = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(_.split('\t')).map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6))).toDF("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7")
    val res = df.explode("c7","c8")((x:String) => x.split('|')).drop("c7")

    res.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","\t").save(args(1))
  }
}
```

And finally, this is my command to run scala jar.

```
spark-submit \
        --class App \
        --master spark://spark.dso.xxxx \
        --executor-memory 10G \
        /home/jumbo/user/sclee/dt/jars/scala_tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
        /user/sclee/data_big/ /user/sclee/output_scala_csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala object name should be associated with package name while submitting the scala-spark job, and therefore your `--class` configuration will be:

```
--class com.sclee.scala0.App
```

Use above configuration while submitting the application and it will eliminate your error.

Update your maven `pom.xml` dependency section with following:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It will allow your `pom.xml` to download your Scala version compatible jars from remote repository.

I hope it will help.

Comment: There is no matched version when I changed the variables you suggested. Since scala.version is 2.11.x and there is no compatible version with 2.11.x in spark-mllib and spark-sql lib.

Comment: Which version of Scala you are using ? In your pom.xml you have mentioned 2.10.4.

Comment: spark-mlib and spark-sql libraries are available for Scala 2.11.X. You can follow this link to get its maven repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark but since your cluster Scala version is 2.10 You should also use the same in your `pom.xml`